# Running __main__.py script with python . (dot)

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to understand why a  `__main__.py`  file could be run from shell issuing
 `python .`  within the folder where said file is located.

How does this work? What does the `.` stand for, and why is not the file name needed?

Where is the dot coming from?. Given a bash script, say

```
#!/bin/bash
#Dummy bash script
echo "This is a dummy bash script"
```

saved as  `dummy_bash_script`.
I could run it, opening a terminal from the folder where it is located, issuing

```
$ ./dummy_bash_script
```

providing hence an explicit path (`./`). Are the two dots related? Does the dot in  `python .`  indicate anything about the current directory? If yes, where is the backslash gone?

Another use for the  `.` (dot) in bash is as a shortcut for  `source` , but I fail to see any connection.

And why is not the file name needed, in  `python .` ? I understand as a file is ran as a script "somewhere under the bonnet" it is assigned the name "**main**". That is, the special variable  `__name`  gets an assignment,  `__name__ = "__main__"`.

But how does this exactly work as a  `__main__`  file is executed as script using the dot, i.e. how can this file be ran with  `python .`, without file name?

Thanks

Comment: The `.` always refers to the current folder. That's why `./script.sh` refers to a script in the current folder. Executing `.` will execute the current folder as a module (aka the `__main__.py` file in python)

Comment: Short version: `__main__.py` is a special script that is run when the folder/package itself is run as a script, rather than being imported as a module, so `python .` is just saying "treat the current folder as the script to run". `__main__.py` doesn't mean anything to anything but Python though, so you can't use a similar trick without explicitly running `python`. But yes, the `.` in both cases means the same thing; the current directory.

Comment: The `.` shortcut in bash is different, referring to the current interpreter context. All the rest refer to the current context. Bash, unlike python, can't execute folders

Comment: if you don't like `./` you can always add `.` to `PATH`  in windows style but I strongly suggest not to.

Comment: Oh no actually I like it aplenty, just wanted to understand it, thanks